# Find all nodes that has child with attribute as group of other nodes

Tags: xslt

I have this:

```
<SOLUTION> 
<CONFIGURATION>  
 <INST NR="1">  
  <CSTICS>  
   <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TXT1" VALUE="GLOBAL1"/>  
   <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TXT2" VALUE="GLOBAL2"/>  
   <CSTIC CHARC="MY_RULES" VALUE="ABCDE123/1:R1"/>  
   <CSTIC CHARC="MY_RULES" VALUE="FGH112/1:R1"/>  
   <CSTIC CHARC="MY_RULES" VALUE="IJKL/5:R1"/>
   <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT3" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/> 
  </CSTICS>
 </INST>
 <PARTS>
  <INST NR="2">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT2_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT2_5" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST>
  <INST NR="3">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT3_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT3_5" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST>
  <INST NR="4">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT4_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="RULE" VALUE="ABCDE123/1"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST> 
  <INST NR="5">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT5_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="RULE" VALUE="ABCDE123/1"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST> 
  <INST NR="6">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT6_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="RULE" VALUE="FGH112/1"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST>
  <INST NR="7">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT7_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="RULE" VALUE="ABCDE123/1"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST>
  <INST NR="8">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT8_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT8_5" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST> 
  <INST NR="9">
   <CSTICS>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT9_4" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="RULE" VALUE="IJKL/5"/>
    <CSTIC CHARC="SOME_TEXT9_5" VALUE="GLOBAL3"/>
   </CSTICS>
  </INST>
 </PARTS>
</CONFIGURATION> 
</SOLUTION>
```

And I want this:

```
<OBJ NAME="4">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT4_4"/>
</OBJ>
<OBJ NAME="5">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT5_4"/>
</OBJ>
<OBJ NAME="6">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT6_4"/>
</OBJ>
<OBJ NAME="7">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT7_4"/>
</OBJ>
<OBJ NAME="9">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT9_4"/>
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT9_5"/>
</OBJ>
```

And I do this:

```
<xsl:template match="//INST[./CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='RULE']/@VALUE=substring-before(/SOLUTION/CONFIGURATION/INST/CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='MY_RULES']/@VALUE,':')]">
   <OBJ NAME="@NR">
     <xsl:for-each select="./CSTICS/CSTIC[starts-with(@CHARC,'SOME_TEXT')]">
      <EL NAME="@CHARC"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </OBJ>
```

But, I get this:

```
<OBJ NAME="4">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT4_4"/>
</OBJ>
<OBJ NAME="5">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT5_4"/>
</OBJ>
<OBJ NAME="7">
 <EL NAME="SOME_TEXT7_4"/>
</OBJ>
```

As **=substring-before(/SOLUTION/CONFIGURATION/INST/CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='MY_RULES']/@VALUE,':')** use only first MY RULES with value **ABCDE123/1:R1** and not others.
I am stuck and I don't know where I am wrong.

Is any idea why this use only first MY RULES not all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use XSLT 2.0 you can move the `substring-before` call into the last step of the path expression:

```
<xsl:template match="INST[CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='RULE']/@VALUE = /SOLUTION/CONFIGURATION/INST/CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='MY_RULES']/substring-before(@VALUE,':')]">
    <OBJ NAME="{@NR}">
        <xsl:for-each select="CSTICS/CSTIC[starts-with(@CHARC,'SOME_TEXT')]">
            <EL NAME="{@CHARC}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </OBJ>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0 I think you need to move the check into an `xsl:if` as there you can use `current()` to compare the matched element and the other elements substring-before:

```
<xsl:template match="INST">
    <xsl:if test="/SOLUTION/CONFIGURATION/INST/CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='MY_RULES'][substring-before(@VALUE,':') = current()/CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='RULE']/@VALUE]">
        <OBJ NAME="{@NR}">
            <xsl:for-each select="CSTICS/CSTIC[starts-with(@CHARC, 'SOME_TEXT')]">
                <EL NAME="{@CHARC}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </OBJ>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, thank You. I use XSLT2.0 (Firefox for testing) and I get:
"Error loading stylesheet: XPath parse failure: Name or Nodetype test expected:"
It is because **substring-before**.
For testing, i removed ":R1" and I didn't need that function and works as it should works but with that function I get that error.

Comment: I am afraid the XSLT support in all mayor browsers like Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge and Safari is restricted to XSLT 1.0 so the suggestion I made first with XSLT 2.0 requires you to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, Altova, XmlPrime, you can't use that approach with a function call in the last step with XSLT in the browser. The second suggestion should do however.